# How to download binary data received via CURL in php?

Tags: php, http, curl, binary

I'm trying to download a file that is returned in binary format in CURL request. But the downloaded file is corrupted. This is what my CURL request looks like -

```
$url = "some api URL. It is not a file URL.";


$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($resource, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // disable certificate verification
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token"));
$file = curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);


$file_array = explode("\n\r", $file, 2);
$header_array = explode("\n", $file_array[0]);
foreach($header_array as $header_value) {
    $header_pieces = explode(':', $header_value);
    if(count($header_pieces) == 2) {
        $headers[$header_pieces[0]] = trim($header_pieces[1]);
    }
}

header('Content-type: ' . $headers['Content-Type']);
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=thiisit.docx");
echo substr($file_array[1], 1);
die;
```

And this is what response headers looks like -

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 09:55:27 GMT
    [2] => Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains
    [3] => Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="xxxxx"; pin-sha256="xxxxx"; pin-sha256="xxxxx"; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hpkp-report/00D";
    [4] => Expect-CT: max-age=86400, report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/00D"
    [5] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    [6] => X-Robots-Tag: none
    [7] => X-B3-TraceId: xxxxx
    [8] => X-B3-SpanId: xxxxxx
    [9] => X-B3-Sampled: 0
    [10] => Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
    [11] => Set-Cookie: BrowserId=kv6o3EeqFV; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 09-Jun-2021 09:55:27 GMT; Max-Age=31536000
    [12] => Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=1468/5000000
    [13] => Content-Type: application/octetstream
    [14] => Transfer-Encoding: chunked
)
```

And the file type which I'm trying to download is `.docx` 
And data received in binary format looks something like -

```
[1] => 
PK!ߤ�lZ [Content_Types].xml �(����n�0E�����Ub袪*�>�-R�{V��Ǽ��QU�
l"%3��3Vƃ�ښl    �w%�=���^i7+���-d&�0�A�6�l4��L60#�Ò�S
```

Above data is just a snippet, not the complete binary response.

Could you please help me to download this file.
Thanks !!
I got the reference from the URL - https://ryansechrest.com/2012/07/send-and-receive-binary-files-using-php-and-curl/

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get a file you can also use **file_get_contents()**

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer($contents);

header('Content-Type:'.$mime_type);
print $contents;
```

[PHP file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: thanks for prompt reply. But how should I suppose to manage OAUTH here in the  method explained by you.  I get 2 things in response - 1.)  Header infoormations   2.) And binary data.      Also it is the API URL, which I'm trying to hit, not the file URL.

Comment: Base on your question you didn't specify any of this, can you update your question and add this requirements.